# Convert SQLserver function to postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following code written in SQL Server but I am migrating to PostgreSQL in this way I have errors.

This is my SQLserver code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Teltonika_FunElement(
     @Raw   VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@Tipo  INT
)
RETURNS @Elements2 TABLE(ID INT, Nombre VARCHAR(MAX), Value VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Elements TABLE(ID INT, Nombre VARCHAR(MAX), Value VARCHAR(MAX))

    DECLARE
         @i     INT=1
        ,@y     INT=1
        ,@Len   INT
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF @Tipo=1
    BEGIN
        SET @Len = LEN(@Raw)/4

        WHILE @i<=@Len
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Elements
            SELECT
                 dbo.Mux_FUN_HexadecimalToDec_v2(SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y, 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y+2, 2)

            SET @y=@y+4

            SET @i = @i+1
        END
    END
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF @Tipo=2
    BEGIN
        SET @Len = LEN(@Raw)/6
        
        WHILE @i<=@Len
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Elements
            SELECT
                 dbo.Mux_FUN_HexadecimalToDec_v2(SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y, 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y+2, 4)

            SET @y=@y+6

            SET @i = @i+1
        END
    END
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF @Tipo=4
    BEGIN
        SET @Len = LEN(@Raw)/10
        
        WHILE @i<=@Len
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Elements
            SELECT
                 dbo.Mux_FUN_HexadecimalToDec_v2(SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y, 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y+2, 8)

            SET @y=@y+10

            SET @i = @i+1
        END
    END
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF @Tipo=8
    BEGIN
        SET @Len = LEN(@Raw)/18
        
        WHILE @i<=@Len
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Elements
            SELECT
                 dbo.Mux_FUN_HexadecimalToDec_v2(SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y, 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(@Raw, @y+2, 16)

            SET @y=@y+18

            SET @i = @i+1
        END
    END
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    INSERT INTO @Elements2
    SELECT
         E.ID
        ,PropertyName
        ,CASE
            WHEN (TypeParser = 'INT' AND Active=1)                  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), dbo.Mux_FUN_HexadecimalToDec_v2(Value))
            WHEN (TypeParser = 'DECIMAL(18,1)/1000' AND Active=1)   THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), (dbo.Mux_FUN_HexadecimalToDec_v2(Value)/1000))
         ELSE Value
         END Value
    FROM @Elements E
    LEFT JOIN Mux_Teltonika_Tbl_ElementsConf TE ON TE.PropertyID=E.ID
    
    RETURN
END
```

so far I managed to write this in postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Teltonika_FunElement(
     Raw    CHARACTER VARYING,
     Tipo   INTEGER
)
RETURNS Elements2 TEMP TABLE(ID INT, Nombre CHARACTER VARYING, Value1 CHARACTER VARYING)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE Elements TEMP TABLE(ID INT, Nombre CHARACTER VARYING, Value1 CHARACTER VARYING)

    DECLARE
         i      INT=1;
         y      INT=1;
         Len1   INT;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF Tipo=1 THEN
    
        Len1    := LENGTH(Raw)/4;

        WHILE i<=Len1
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO Elements
            SELECT
                 hex_to_int(SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y FOR 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y+2 FOR 2);

                 y  :=  y+4;

                 i  :=  i+1;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF Tipo = 2 THEN 
    BEGIN
        Len1 := LENGTH(Raw)/6;
        
        WHILE i<=Len1
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO Elements
            SELECT
                 hex_to_int(SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y FOR 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y+2 FOR 4);

                y := y+6;

                i := i+1;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF Tipo = 4 THEN
    
        Len1 := LENGTH(Raw)/10;
        
        WHILE i<=Len1
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO Elements
            SELECT
                 hex_to_int(SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y FOR 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y+2 FOR 8);

                y := y+10;

                i := i+1;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF Tipo = 8 THEN
    
        Len1 := LENGTH(Raw)/18;
        
        WHILE i<=Len1
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO Elements
            SELECT
                 hex_to_int(SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y FOR 2))
                ,NULL
                ,SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y+2 FOR 16);

                y := y+18;

                i := i+1;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    INSERT INTO Elements2
    SELECT
         E.ID
        ,PropertyName
        ,CASE
            WHEN (TypeParser = 'INT' AND Active=1);                 THEN (hex_to_int(Value1):: VARCHAR)
            WHEN (TypeParser = 'DECIMAL(18,1);/1000' AND Active=1); THEN (hex_to_int(Value1)/1000)::VARCHAR)
         ELSE Value
         END Value
    FROM Elements E
    LEFT JOIN Teltonika_Tbl_ElementsConf TE ON TE.PropertyID=E.ID;
    
    RETURN
END;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "TEMP"
> LINE 5: RETURNS Elements2 TEMP TABLE (ID INT, Name CHARACTER VARYIN ...

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What does it do? It looks like it splits a string into rows? That can be done with built-in functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has not table type variables. Instead you can use a arrays. The arguments of functions are probably arrays too with own reimplementation in MSSQL. Inside Postgres you can pass arguments in array format - without bad readable own code.

When array is of composite type, then you should to define composite type first:

```
CREATE TYPE element_type AS (id int, nombre varchar, value varchar);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION teltonika_funelement(raw varchar, tipo int)
RETURNS element_type[] AS $$
DECLARE elements element_type[] DEFAULT '{}';
BEGIN
  ...
  elements := elements ||
                ROW(hex_to_int(SUBSTRING(raw FROM y FOR 2))
                   ,NULL
                   ,SUBSTRING(Raw FROM y+2 FOR 8));

  ...
  RETURNS elements;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Using camel case notation for variables, arguments is bad practice (due case insensitivity of identifiers).

Programming stored procedures in PostgreSQL is pretty different than in T-SQL in MS SQL. It is much more similar to programming in classical procedural languages (and it is much more similar to Oracle PL/SQL). Please, forgot all what you know, and start from ground. [PLpgSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) is good (and not too long - less than 50 pages), start by reading this doc.

You can use temp table

```
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elements(id int, nombre varchar, value1 varchar)
  DELETE FROM elements;
  ...
```

But using temp tables for few values (less than thousands) is pretty expensive and slow.

There is another error. `DECLARE` clause is before block (before `BEGIN` keyword). So good to start with documentation - PL/pgSQL is level better language than T-SQL, but it is different language, different environment.

Comment: I understood the explanation, I only generated a question as I do to make an inner join with table teltonika_tbl_elementsconf and then I return this, here is the last part of the code  INSERT INTO Elements2
 SELECT
   E.ID
  ,PropertyName
  ,CASE
   WHEN (TypeParser = 'INT' AND Active=1) THEN (hex_to_int(Value1):: VARCHAR)
   WHEN (TypeParser = 'DECIMAL(18,1);/1000' AND Active=1) THEN (hex_to_int(Value1)/1000)::VARCHAR)
   ELSE Value
   END Value
 FROM Elements E
 LEFT JOIN Teltonika_Tbl_ElementsConf TE ON TE.PropertyID=E.ID;

Comment: @RollerFernandez You can use a function `unnest` - this transform a array to table, or you can return a array again.

Comment: Thanks for help;